# How to multiply two dataframes if they have the same index value along the corresponding row?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have something like this (which may have the forecast_date index repeated):

```
df1: 
forecast_date    value

2015-04-11       18952
2015-04-12       18938
2015-04-13       18940
2015-04-14       18949
2015-04-15       18955
2015-04-16       18956
...
2015-04-02       18950
2015-04-03       18968
```

I also have another dataframe that is like this (indices here are never duplicated):

```
df2:
date           value
2015-04-01     1.3
2015-04-02     1.35
2015-04-03     1.34
2015-04-04     1.45
....
```

I want to multiple the df1 row value by the df2 row value if their indices match. What is an elegant way to do this in pandas? This is probably really easy and I am just overlooking it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you set the index to be the dates for both df's then multiplication will align where the indices match:

```
In [46]:

df['value'] * df1['value']
Out[46]:
2015-04-01         NaN
2015-04-02    25582.50
2015-04-03    25417.12
2015-04-04         NaN
2015-04-11         NaN
2015-04-12         NaN
2015-04-13         NaN
2015-04-14         NaN
2015-04-15         NaN
2015-04-16         NaN
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

The question is whether you want `NaN` values where the rows are missing or not.

**EDIT**

If you have duplicate date values then what you could do is left merge the other df's value column and then multiply the 2 columns so the following should work:

```
In [58]:

df1.rename(columns={'value':'other_value'}, inplace=True)
merged = df.merge(df1, left_on='forecast_date', right_on='date', how='left')
merged['new_value'] = merged['value'] * merged['other_value']
merged
Out[58]:
  forecast_date  value        date  other_value  new_value
0    2015-04-11  18952         NaN          NaN        NaN
1    2015-04-12  18938         NaN          NaN        NaN
2    2015-04-13  18940         NaN          NaN        NaN
3    2015-04-14  18949         NaN          NaN        NaN
4    2015-04-15  18955         NaN          NaN        NaN
5    2015-04-16  18956         NaN          NaN        NaN
6    2015-04-02  18950  2015-04-02         1.35   25582.50
7    2015-04-03  18968  2015-04-03         1.34   25417.12
```

The above assumes that the date columns have not been set as the index already.

Comment: I get "ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis" because some indices are duplicates.

Comment: Where you have duplicate dates are the values also duplicated? Another method would be to left merge the value column from df1 to df on the dates and then multiply the 2 columns

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of a array to store the values. And then look through arrayA if the same value occurs in arrayB. If yes, do a calculation.

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
df1.multiply(df2)
```

check pandas.DataFrame.multiply